# How to load Keras on RStudio VM on google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created a RStudio instance on google cloud and is trying to perform deep learning with neural network on the cloud. After installing the package Keras and executing install_keras(), there is an error message:

> Error: Prerequisites for installing TensorFlow not available. Execute the following at a terminal to install the prerequisites: $ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-virtualenv

I tried to install python-pip python-virtualenv through google cloud console, but it didn't work. Does anyone know how to fix the problem?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Which steps have you taken? Which is the operating system and the version you are using? when you say that it didn't work, can you explain better why(for example can you provide the output of the commands you used)?

Comment: @GalloCedrone I installed RStudio as a VM instance on Compute Engine API, and is trying to install Keras package on the RStudio VM. I used `install.pacakges("keras")` and `library(keras)` all went through, but when I execute `install_keras()` the error message appeared. Without `install_keras()` I cannot perform neural network analysis. I install RStudio on ubuntu.

Comment: @GalloCedrone The command I used for installation: `$ sudo gcloud compute instances create rstudio --image-family ubuntu-1604-lts --image-project ubuntu-os-cloud  --machine-type n1-standard-8 --zone us-west1-a`